# why my thread is stopped inside handler after getting Geocode response?

Tags: android, multithreading, geocoding

i create a new thread in my Activity. Inside it's run(..) i write a code to get Geo-code from Google. When i got JSON response and after processing i send it to handler. Inside handler i found new thread is died .

Here is my run()

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(4000);
            Log.d("Thread", "---Is Running---");
            getCityName = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");
            Log.d("----getCityName----", getCityName);
            
            HttpRetriever httpObj = new HttpRetriever();
            String geocodeUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                    + getCityName + "&sensor=true";
            String url = geocodeUrl.replace(" ", "%20");

            Log.d("----geocodeUrl----", url);

            geocodeResponse = httpObj.retrieve(url);
            Log.d("----Json Response----", geocodeResponse);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(geocodeResponse);

            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results");

            if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {

                jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
                jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("geometry");
                JSONObject location = (JSONObject) jsonObject
                        .get("location");
                Double lat = (Double) location.get("lat");
                Double lng = (Double) location.get("lng");

                mypoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000),
                        (int) (lng * 1000000));

                Log.d("-----Lat LOng-----", "" + lat + " " + lng);

                addOverlayOnMap(mypoint, getCityName);

                myMap.getController().animateTo(mypoint);
                myMap.getController().setZoom(6);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    }
```

Here is my Handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        pdDialog.dismiss();
        if (geocodeResponse != null) {

            if (t.isAlive() == true) {
                Log.v("------Thread-----",
                        "---Inside Handler----Thread is Alive!!!!----");

            } else {
                Log.v("------Thread-----",
                        "---Inside Handler---Thread is Died!!!!----");

            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Ya got the json",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

};
```

**I just wondering why my thread is stopped inside handler? Though i don't stop it any where.I test codes in emulator**

**If u have the issue, can share.**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you do some UI opreations in your thread?